# python function must return not "None" but "False"

Tags: python-2.7, return, function

i need help. It is necessary that the function does return not "None" but "False" if there is no file. sorry for my english)

```
def file_search(folder, filename):
way=folder[0]
if filename in folder:
            return way+'/'+filename
for item in folder:

    if isinstance(item,list):
        found_file=file_search(item,filename)
        if found_file!=None:
            return way + '/' + found_file
print file_search([ 'D:', ['recycle bin'], ['tmp', ['old'], ['new folder1', 'asd.txt', 'asd.bak', 'find.me.bak' ] ], 'hey.py'], 'find.me')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put "return False" at the end of the function.

Currently, if your 'if' statements fail, there's no return statement for it to fall back on so the function returns None by default.

Comment: If I simply add at the end of the function "return False", there is a "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects" in line 11

Answer (score 0):

```
def file_search(folder, filename):
way=folder[0]
if filename in folder:
        return way+'/'+filename
for item in folder:

if isinstance(item,list):
    found_file=file_search(item,filename)
    if found_file!=None:
        return way + '/' + found_file
print file_search([ 'D:', ['recycle bin'], ['tmp', ['old'], ['new folder1', 'asd.txt', 'asd.bak', 'find.me.bak' ] ], 'hey.py'], 'find.me')
else: 
    return False
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in file_search
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects

Comment: of course. and "print" it as an example of a function call

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake) Default function should return False, I forgot to check (8 line ) to fix None --> False

```
def file_search(folder, filename):
way=folder[0]
if filename in folder:
    return way+'/'+filename
for item in folder:
    if isinstance(item,list):
        found_file=file_search(item,filename)
        if found_file!=False:
            return way + '/' + found_file
return False
```